# C compiler for Android apps on Linux (with examples and emulator)

Tags: android, linux, c, emulator, compiler

I would like to make some simple 2D single player games (with no need for fancy graphics) for Android devices.

I am **not** looking for a full blown IDE, but just for a compiler that works under Linux and compiles C (or C++) code for Android. If it is possible to make gcc to do that, that would be fine too.

Also, some simple examples would come in handy for getting started and an Android emulator (also for Linux) would be nice to have in order speed up the development - I want to do most of the stuff on my Linux machine and put it on the Android device only after making some significant progress.

Comment: You also need the various libraries for Linux, etc.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I would guess so. But is there a list or a package of libraries available? Just the minimum of libraries for Android game development would be ideal.

Comment: The minimum for "games development" doesn't leave a lot out especially if you don't specify what sort of games - a text only guess the number game has very different requirements to a 3D Multiplayer RPG when you think about it.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, that's the good point, thanks! I've edited my question to clarify that I just want to make some simple 2D single player games, nothing too fancy. For example, games like 2048, Pong, Arkanoid, Flappy Bird, etc.

Comment: I.e. I don't need anything more than what I can do with 2d context of HTML5 canvas with JavaScript except that I want this to be a native Android app (instead of html+js) with ability to save some stuff, e.g. hi-scores, custom maps,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need the compile tool chain, with the libraries and the testing tools such as the emulation, installation tools, etc. and examples/documentation you might as well bite the bullet and download the full SDK in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). You have a choice on any platform of just downloading the command line tools (SDK) or the full studio, (IDE), but for Linux the studio download is significantly smaller for the IDE, *273 MB for IDE, 311 MB without!*

- Price: **Free, Gratis**
- Platform(s): **Linux**, OS-X & MS-Win
- USB Test & Debug on actual device(s)
- or Test & Debug on [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)
- Android Virtual Device Manager allows you to install, create and maintain a range of possible target environments.
- The IDE is based on Intellij and provides tailored code completion, etc.
- Automatic Build systems & git/svn support
- Code templates & sample apps
- Built in Lint checker & static analysis
- Testing tools
- Java, C++ & Android NDK supported
- Translations Editor
- Vector Asset Studio
- Built-in support for Google Cloud Platform
- Publishing tools including App signing.

Main Window Screenshot from the [user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html).
[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks bloated and confusing! But I gave it a try and installed it and it turns out to be even more confusing than I thought. I couldn't figure out how to make even a simple Hello world program. Also, the "user guide" is more of an advertisement of the countless features (most of which I probably won't need) than something that will help you get started. 

The emulator feature is nice (although I had to update Java to make it work).

Comment: If there is no reasonable alternative, I guess I'll have to use this. Do you know where can I find some beginners' tutorials?

Comment: http://ssearch.oreilly.com/?q=android+programming or https://developer.android.com/training/index.html might be good places to start.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials, this should make Android Studio useful. :)